# Reinforcement learning using univalent and multivalent heterogeneous features

Tags: python, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, preprocessing

### Problem introduction

I have a game in which human players play levels (just like the famous casual game candy crush) where each level has its own properties and its own difficulty. In said game, the only variable that I, myself, have control over is the level's difficulty. I also have means to empirically measure some metrics that reflect the engagement of a player based on the findings of '[Quantifying human engagement](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-020-60742-8)'.

### Problem formulation

Based on the data that I collect from the players, I am able to reproduce the above-cited paper's findings by empirically computing a player's *engagement* from my dataset as follows :

$$
\bar{t_a}(n) = \frac{\bar{t_p^{emp}}(n)}{p_c(n)} = \text{Reward}
$$

Where $\bar{t_p^{emp}}(n)$ is just the average number of attempts needed by players that passed level $n$ to pass it and $p_c(n)$ is the churn probability defined by the total number of players that abandoned at level $n$ divided by the total number of players that played level $n$.

The set of actions that reflect the difficulty of a level which I have control over is represented as :

$$
\text{Action} \in \{A,B,C\}
$$

where each of the three options $A$, $B$ or $C$ represent a degree of difficulty. I also have the option of making difficulty actions randomly at first in order to learn a player's preferences in real time and its impact on the above-defined reward. Based on my findings so far, the actions have an impact on the reward.

### Data collected

I collect data that represent features for thousands of players, each of which is given a unique $id$, in the following form :

- Univalent features (one value per row, can be numerical or categorical)
- Multivalent features (short time series have a fixed length of $k$ elements in the past)

An example of my data looks like this :

```py
ID        X1               X2              X3          Reward      Action
1    [1,2,3,1,..]    [True, False, ...]    0.33        0.33         A
1    [5,1,2,3,..]    [True, True, ...]     0.6         0.5          B
2    [0.5,1,..]      [False, False,...]    0.6         0.5          C
```

I can have different numbers of observations for different $id$'s (so for example, $12$ observations for $id_1$ and $50$ for $id_2$) But each row can be a standalone learning instance that contain the full historical data for the same $id$ of course.

### Modeling approach

I would like to find a modeling approach that returns one of the three actions available in order to maximize the reward (human engagement) based on what has been given in the past. This makes me think that it is a reinforcement learning problem. However, I have yet to find any resources or tutorials on how to preprocess such data nor did I find any models that handle such cases.

The only paper that I came across that discusses this problem is [deep learning for youtube recommendation](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/45530.pdf) where the authors talk about univalent and multivalent features (so tabular data and time series data mixed together, same as my case) then they use an embedding layer to transform the feature space into a single format input for a deep neural network. However, the authors do not share any code to reproduce their preprocessing techniques.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate on how the reward is computed? I mean, how does the reward value depend on your prediction?

Comment: Also, you really need to give some context. What is the actual problem? Are the answers ground truth answers? Here it seems that there is a mixture of a prediction problem and an optimization problem. If you could elaborate more on where do these data come from, do you have access to a simulator/environment and what the actual problem is we will be able to help you or point you to the relevant literature.

Comment: Thank you both for your questions. I have edited the question to include more context. In short, no I do not have access to a simulator but I do have an environment where I can give one of the three options randomly for each player. So the `answer` column is not ground truth since it can be given randomly at first in order to learn a player's preferences. Some sequence of answers given may lead to a low reward and others to a higher reward. The reward is computed empirically from the data and the aim is to give answers for each player to maximize the reward in the long run! I hope it helps.

Comment: So you want an agent that will output an action (A, B, C) which modulates the difficulty of a game that a human plays in order for the human to perform maximally at the game. Or, the "reward" is not an actual performance measure of how the human player performed but instead a pre-calculated quantity that depends on the action sequence the human generated while playing the game?

Comment: By the way, some good practices that you might use in the future: start first by describing the TASK: e.g. I have a game where a human player tries to achieve X. I assign to that human player a level of difficulty then human gets this reward according to...then describe what DATA you collect: e.g. I collect all human actions etc and THEN describe what you are trying to achieve and what the technical PROBLEM is. This will help everyone to clearly understand what you want to do and potentially mathematically formulate your problem :)

Comment: Yes exactly. I would like an agent that would take one of the three pre-defined actions to modulate difficulty in the game for human players in order to maximize engagement. The reward reflects an engagement that can be computed empirically from the data using the number of attempts and empirical churn for each level. Said action should, in theory, have an impact on this reward. Thank you for the advice, I will re-edit the post and introduce the problem first!

Comment: Seems way better! Few more questions: when do you change the difficulty? Do you change it during the player playing one level or after it has completed one level you change it for the next one? Also from what i understood, you do not have the game simulator (candy crash) right? The other thing that I want to confirm is that it seems that your reward is dependent on other players correct?

Comment: I change the difficulty just before a player starts their next stage since I seek to optimize gameplay for each player in real time. I do not have a game simulator but I am allowed to randomly send difficulties for a cohort of players for the game I seek to optimize (so I do have access to the real thing with real-world data for the game). The reward is computed from averages from all levels so it is more dependent on the level and how many attempts is takes, on average, for players to pass each level and how many people on average leave at this particular level.

Comment: I do not have the perfect answer but i do have an answer to few of the problems you are facing: First of all without a simulator you will need Offline RL (check Sergey Levine's review). Offline RL tries to solve the problem of having no access to a simulator but have access to data (the data you have collected).

Comment: One major problem with your formulation that I find is the reward. The reward is assigned when all players have finished the game. This is a very hard credit assignment problem. Imagine that your agent is an RL observer that wants to learn to associate a particular behavior (data) to difficulties in order to maximize score (engagement). If that score is calculated after all players have finished the game then you won't be able to optimize engagement easily.

Comment: The way you have formalized the problem i was trying to find a way to frame it either as a bandit problem, RL (sequential problem) or a prediction problem (SL). If you choose optimization then your reward function won't provide a good learning signal. Is there another metric that you could use? You could definitely use an LSTM to create a sequence embedding and then concatenate with other one-dimensional inputs. However the reward depends on other players and cannot be computed for a certain amount of steps in the game.

Comment: Another option to think is to have some kind of "meta-features" extracted from the current ones. Basically you categorize the sequential data and map them to a metric or class and then use that predictive model to generate your state features in a RL setting. The reward that you have in my opinion is like giving MVP prize to an NBA player after a full season and dependent on other players as well. In other words your reward depends on the performance of the other players as well and is coming AFTER they all have played the game. Is there a correlation between your reward and performance?

Comment: To get a bit deeper in the reward problem: if you have two groups of participants and you calculate the reward for each group's dataset, the same behavior will have different reward outcome depending on which group belongs. So your agent will face non-stationarity in the reward function as that will change overtime depending the participants and their performance.

Comment: Thank you for your input @Constantinos. I see the issue your raise regarding the reward. It is indeed computed once the phase of randomly giving difficulty options is completed (whether it is a week or a month). Of course, if we happen to have many 'skilled' players in a certain group then the reward will be naturally high since the numerator is computed based on the number of attempts to pass (skilled players will need fewer attempts than less skilled players). This means that there is indeed a correlation between reward and performance of players.

Comment: The thing is, this is the only reward that I could come up with that made sense. Based on the articles that I have been reading, the reward should not be based on the physical time as in how frequently a player plays and for how long since casual games are played in short sessions in short breaks which are hard to predict. Therefore, they compute engagement as a function of progression in the game e.g. how many levels have been played, how many levels it takes to pass etc...

Comment: Finally, I thought about building a neural network architecture with three outputs for prediction: $\bar{t_a}$ for each of the three difficulties $\{A, B, C\}$ then choosing the difficulty that yields the highest predicted $\bar{t_a}$. This way it is framed as a prediction problem and not a RL problem. But after you brought up the issue of the dependence between the reward and the performance of players (and the data collection period for that matter), I am not sure that it is a good idea anymore.

Comment: You might be able to do what you suggest (having the problem framed as a prediction problem) but in order to be, let's say, approximately close to the "optimal" that RL would potentially find, you would need lots of data and a large pool of participants. Maybe, if you could test  the same participant in multiple difficulties you might be able to associate behavior with engagement. For sure though you won't be able to optimize this as you don't have the simulator and the reward is dependent on all players' performance.